# JSON array as select options and null displayname

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I cannot get a multi select to populate properly.

1. Even though I'm specifying the `keyField` and `valueField`, I'm getting JSON as option values
2. `name` is null and shouldn't be

Example:

```
<option value="0">{
    "id": 8263,
    "name": null,
    "sort": "1"
}</option>
```

`clients` MySQL table columns: `id, name_en, name_fr...`

`Client` Entity:

```
protected $_virtual = [
            'name',
        ];

protected function _getName()
{
    if (Configure::read('wetkit.lang') == 'fr'){
        return $this->get('name_fr');
    } else {
        return $this->get('name_en');
    }
}
```

`ClientsTable` table:

```
$this->setDisplayField('name');
```

Controller:

```
//build query to highlight selected clients
$selected_clients = $this->Clients->find()
->select(['id' => 'id','name' => 'name_'.$this->lang,'sort'=>1])
->where(['id in' => $user_clients]);

$clients = $this->Clients->find()
->select(['id' => 'id','name' => 'name_'.$this->lang,'sort'=>2])
->where(['id not in' => $user_clients]);

$clients->unionAll($selected_clients)->epilog('order by sort asc, name asc');
```

SQL:

```
(
  SELECT 
    id AS `id`, 
    name_en AS `name`, 
    2 AS `sort` 
  FROM 
    clients Clients 
  WHERE 
    id not in (8263)
) 
UNION ALL 
  (
    SELECT 
      id AS `id`, 
      name_en AS `name`, 
      1 AS `sort` 
    FROM 
      clients Clients 
    WHERE 
      id in (8263)
  ) 
order by 
  sort asc, 
  name asc
```

In the view:

```
<?= $this->Form->control('clients._ids', 
                ['options' => $clients, 
                'label'=>__('Client'), 
                'keyField' => 'id', 
                'valueField' => 'name',
                'values' => $user_clients]) ?>
```

Solution:

This seems to work. I did have to figure out the appropriate sort to reflect the ORM's field name (ie. `Client__name_en`). I also wrapped this up in a component and can use app wide using other models.

```
//build query to highlight selected clients
$selected_clients = $this->Clients->find()
->select(['id','name_en','name_fr','sort'=>1])
->where(['id in' => $user_clients]);

$clients = $this->Clients->find()
->select(['id','name_en','name_fr','sort'=>2])
->where(['id not in' => $user_clients]);

$clients->unionAll($selected_clients)
->epilog('order by sort, Clients__name_'.$this->lang);

$clients = $clients->combine('id','name_'.$this->lang);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keyField` and `valueField` options belong to the `list` finder, not to form controls.

```php
$clients
    ->unionAll($selected_clients)
    ->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id', 
        'valueField' => 'name',
    ])
    // ...
```

Looks a bit weird, but finders can be chained, so to speak. Alternatively you can use `Collection::combine()` directly, that is what is applied automatically when using the `list` finder:

```php
'options' => $clients->combine('id', 'name'),
// ...
```

And `name` is `null` because you do not select the `name_en` or `name_fr` fields that your entity tries to lookup. Selecting a value as `name` will not circumvent the entity's accessor method, it will always run when you try to access the `name` field on the entity, no matter if a value for that field exists.

The accessor method will receive the value of the possibly existing field as its first argument, so you might be able to use that, something along the lines of:

```php
protected function _getName($name)
{
    if ($name !== null) {
        return $name;
    }

    // ...
}
```

However this is all somewhat finicky and error prone, ending up with entity behavior bound to application state doesn't bode well for the future. Maybe you should give CakePHP's built-in translation functionality a try.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Finding Key/Value Pairs](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > combine()](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::combine)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Accessors & Mutators](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Translate](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the tips! getName would actually be a virtual field in our case. IIRC, my understanding was flawed as these cannot be used through finders, only returned after the query, even if they are exposed. I think I could get around this by figuring out how to add a field for my sort, while finding all the fields and doing the union.

Comment: also noting, my getter, is getting model properties or fields depending on the current language in the app... such as name_en or name_fr, which will exist.